# General additive synthesis program

Tags: c, audio, synthesis

I'm attempting to write a general additive synthesis c program that will generate a complex sinusoid created from a sequence of pure sine waves of arbitrary frequency following a single envelope.
The input file will be something of this nature

```
F0     P0                   // a list of up to 100 floats indicating frequencies and 
F1     P1                   // % contribution of this frequency to the sound
F2     P2
....
-1                          // sentinal value to indicate end of frequency list 
B0     A0                   //  first breakpoint
B1     A1
...                         // There can be an arbitary number of breakpoints
```

I want my program to generate a WAV file up to the last breakpoint where all the sine waves will be generated at the given frequencies, scaled to the % contribution as listed, and added together to make the final sound

I've attempted to try some of the c programming out but I'm not naturally a C programming so this is what I've done so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <portsf.h>
#include <math.h>
#ifndef M_PI
#define M_PI (3.141592654)
#endif

// Additive Synthesis

PSF_PROPS props;
props.srate = 44100;
props.chans = 2;
props.samptype = PSF_SAMP_IEEE_FLOAT;
props.format = PSF_STDWAVE;
props.chformat = STDWAVE;

float* frame;

int sampleNumber;
double angleIncrement;
double frequency;
double sampleRate;
int i;
int twopi = 2.0 * M_PI;

ofd = psf_sndCreate(argv[2],&props,0,0,PSF_CREATE_RDWR);

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

sampleNumber = 0;
angleIncrement = twopi * frequency/sampleRate;
while (i < sampleNumber) {
    frame[0] = frame[1] = sin(sampleNumber * angleIncrement);
    sampleNumber++;
    if (fwrite(&sampleout,sizeof(float),1,rawfile) !=1) {
        printf("Error writing to output file.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (i <=1000) 
        fprintf(bpfile, "%ld\t%f\n", i, frame);
    phase += angleIncrement;
    if (phase >= twopi)
        phase -= twopi;
}

phase_offset = -1 * PI / 2;
sample_buffer = (float*) malloc(samples * sizeof(float));
// sample_buffer set back to 0
memset(sample_buffer, 0, sizeof(float)*sampleNumber);

// go through the number of harmonics
for (i = 1; i <= NHARMS; i++) {
    amp = 1.0 / i;
    // go through number of sinusoid components
    for (n = 0; n < sampleNumber; n++) { 
        sample_buffer[n] += amp * cos(i * angleIncrement * n + phase_offset);
    }
}       
}
```

However, I'm not really sure if I'm doing this right at all. Any ideas on how I can fix this and proceed?

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: @AK4749 i'm getting this as an `No such file or directory
gcc: no input files`
But besides that, i'm not entirely sure if i'm actually approaching the problem correctly

Comment: well we can slowly step through this one problem at a time, but it first looks to me like you either have your gcc setup incorrectly or are using the wrong syntax to call it. Can you compile a simple hello world program?

Comment: +1 for making an additive synth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've started noticing more and more little details, the comments start getting annoying to read (but make sure you still answer my compiling Hello World question), so I've coalesced them into this answer and will update it as I see more:

1. as of right now, `frequency` is used only once, and at that time is only `0.0` ever. is that what you want?
2. `i` is initalized to `0`, and `sampleNumber` is also started at `0`. Thus the `while` condition `(i < sampleNumber)` will never execute
3. `i` is never incremented yet you have a `if ( i <= 1000 )` condition, which will thus always evaluate `true`
4. `sampleRate` is initialized to `0.0`, and the first operation on it is to divide by it, which, obviously, is not happy times
5. Obviously pedantic, but the `n` in the bottom most `for` loop is never declared ( `int n; for (n = ....)` as an example.
6. in your `sample_buffer = (float*) malloc(samples * sizeof(float));` line, `samples` should most probably be `sampleNumber`, right? `samples` is never defined

Comment: something was wrong with my gcc but that's fixed so i was able to run the hello world question. 
i've fixed up a few things but i'm still getting tons of errors

Comment: is there an email where i can email you at because this comment thread might go back and forth for a while

Comment: sure, send an email to this: <iklkq@dealja.com> no brackets obviously, and I'll give you better contact info through there - it's a high profile website, don't want to be posting my real email haha. It'll be open for 24 hrs.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with AKA4749, and have one more thing you should do: clip the samples when you add them or you get distortion:

```
if ( sample[i] > 1 ) sample[i] = 1;
else if ( sample[i] < -1 ) sample[i] = -1;
```